# Finding simple path with highest function value sum

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, graph-theory, breadth-first-search, longest-path

I was working on a graph clustering algorithm which requires me to find a value R(u, v) for all pairs of vertices u, v in a undirected graph.

[image]

So, here, R(u, v) is calculated by finding the maximum value over all simple paths from u to v. The function f(u, v) is known and has no special properties that we can use.

I was reading this can be done using a binomial heap efficiently without actually enumerating all simple paths between u and v.

Can someone guide me as to how to approach this? Thanks.

Comment: I believe for the simplest function $f(u_i,u_{i+1})=1$ you're finding the length of the longest path.  I'm pretty sure that's NP hard (certainly finding the longest path is NP hard).

Comment: Okay, the function f is https://ibb.co/cGybXb

Here d(u) represents degree of vertex and w_ij would be weight of edge between i and j. Can something be done now?